# How to implement a DRY copy constructor for a subclass in Scala?

Tags: scala, dry, copy-constructor

I want to make a copy of B, however I do not want to repeat the copying in the subclass (`B`) that goes on in the superclass (`A`).

The solution below is what I cooked up. But I don't like it because it is not a copy constructor and because it is mutating state (vars everywhere).

Scala allows direct call to super **only** from the primary constructor so I had no idea how to create a copy constructor for `B` without repeating the copying code present in the superclass (`A`).

Any suggestions on how to implement a DRY copy constructor or a more elegant way to copy?

```
class A {
  var fieldA=1
  def copyFieldsInto(a:A):Unit={
    a.fieldA=fieldA
  }
}

class B extends A{
  var fieldB=2
  def copyFieldsInto(b:B):Unit=
  {
    super.copyFieldsInto(b)
    b.fieldB=fieldB
  }
}

object Test extends App{
  println("hello")
  val b=new B
  b.fieldA=3
  b.fieldB=4
  val b_copy=new B
  b.copyFieldsInto(b_copy)
  println(b.fieldB,b.fieldA)
  println(b_copy.fieldB,b_copy.fieldA)
}
```

this will print :

```
hello 
(4,3) 
(4,3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this is what you want?

```
class A(val aVal: Int) {
  def this(a:A)={
    this(a.aVal)
  }
}

class B(aVal:Int, val bVal:Int) extends A(aVal){
  def this(b:B) = {
    this(b.aVal, b.bVal)
  }
}

object Test extends App{
  println("hello")                                
  val b=new B(3,4)                                
  val b_copy=new B(b)                             
  println(b.bVal,b.aVal)                          
  println(b_copy.bVal,b_copy.aVal)        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Pihony. I'd like to read about the 'class B(aVal:Int, val bVal:Int) extends A(aVal)' syntax, can you recommend a good source for that? Do you perhaps happen to know where can I find that explained in Odersky's Prog. in Scala book?

Comment: ps. : Just found it in chapter 8 of "Scala for the impatient"

Comment: So it is not possible to call the copy constructor of the superclass? In case the copy constructor does something special related to copying. In other words, this(a:A) cannot be called from this(b:B) ? Like one could in Java.

Comment: If you can provide a concrete example of what you want I might be able to help. But, my guess would be that you should use a method as you did in your answer, or you could do something weird like `this(new A(b).aVal, b.bVal)`. I cannot visualize your need well enough to do more than this answer.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I understand, I might try to find a solution based on the answer you gave, I just have to think a little bit about it.